# User defined filter not working as expected - "contains" interpreted as "ending with"

Tags: excel, vba, vba7

I stumbled over a strange problem today with the "contains" filter creteria used to filter a worksheet based on text input to a activeX text field in a worksheet.

All is shown in the attached screenshot.

The worksheet with the textbox "txtTitleSearch" that receives the input to be searched/filtered as "contains" criteria. Strangly Excel shows it after the code execution as filtered as "ending with" - which is not what was intended.

As prove I show also the worksheet with data over the searchterm.

What can possibly go wrong in this interpretation of vba code, that excel ends up filtering as "ending with"??

I expected filter results to match a "contains" filter with the search term entered.[image]

Comment: Please, do not show code în pictures, since it can be place as  editable, in case that somebody wants making some tests. Then, the used operator for a single criteria is not the most appropriate. Firstly, I would suggest you to use `Operator:=xlFilterValues`. And construction ending in `Text & "*"""` looks strange, except the case when you need that the filtered values to end in double quote (`"`). If not, it should be  `Text & "*"`. In such a way, the rest of the string may be anything, as I suppose you need.

Comment: When creating a 'complicated' ('double-quotes-infested') string, it is good practice to construct it in a separate Sub and test it with *Debug.Print*: `Debug.Print "=*" & "SomeString" & "*"""` will result in `=*SomeString*"` so you immediately see that something's wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set a filter using VBA, Excel attempts to interpret your request and selects the appropriate option for the front end.

In your code, your criteria is:

```
Criteria1:="*" & txtTitelSearch.txt & "*"""
```

This resolves to `*text*"` which, as it ends with a double quote, Excel sets the option to *Ends With*.

If you set your criteria to:

```
Criteria1:="*" & txtTitelSearch.txt & "*"
```

It resolves to `*text*` which, Excel will identify correctly as *Contains* because an asterisk is present at both the start and end of the input.

**To summarise:**

When looking for the text "SearchForThis", you would use the `*` wildcard in the following manner:

- `SearchForThis*` Starts With that text
- `*SearchForThis*` Contains that text
- `*SearchForThis` Ends With that text